# createVerticalGlue() in BoxLayout not functioning

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, layout-manager, boxlayout

I have used the createVerticalGlue() successfully on a number of times.  However in the following screen building code it is not working.  I am still wondering why.

The situation is that I have two JPanels (leftPanel, rightPanel) within another Panel (centralPanel).  Each of these two panels will host two JComponents using a BoxLayout Y-Axis.  I want to distribute the remaining free space before, between and after the two JComponents.

I know that I can use empty borders and rigid areas to solve the problem but it happens that I am a bit hard headed!

My appologies for the long question.

```
    public class MemberGUI extends JFrame {
        JPanel contPane = (JPanel) this.getContentPane();
        JPanel centralPanel = new JPanel();
        JPanel leftPanel = new JPanel();
        JPanel rightPanel = new JPanel();
        JPanel lowerPanel = new JPanel();

        JLabel title = new JLabel("Add/Delete Member");
        JLabel nameLbl = new JLabel("Member's name");
        JLabel idLbl = new JLabel ("Member ID");

        JTextField nameFld = new JTextField(10);
        JTextField idFld = new JTextField(10);


    public void buildMe(){
        //LayoutManagers
        contPane.add(title,BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        contPane.add(centralPanel,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        contPane.add(lowerPanel,BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

        centralPanel.add(leftPanel);
        centralPanel.add(rightPanel);

        leftPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(leftPanel,BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        rightPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(rightPanel,BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        //leftPanel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0,50)));
        leftPanel.add(Box.createVerticalGlue());
        leftPanel.add(idLbl);
        leftPanel.add(Box.createVerticalGlue());
        leftPanel.add(nameLbl);
        leftPanel.add(Box.createVerticalGlue());

        //rightPanel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0,50)));
        rightPanel.add(Box.createVerticalGlue());
        rightPanel.add(idFld);
        rightPanel.add(Box.createVerticalGlue());
        rightPanel.add(nameFld);
        rightPanel.add(Box.createVerticalGlue());


        // JFrame Settings
        this.setSize(500,400);
        this.setResizable(false);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setVisible(true);   

        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you really need to write all this stuf by hand? Why don't you use a GUI builder? NetBeans has a good one. Always when I see somebody with problems related to Swing layout I remember this: http://madbean.com/anim/totallygridbag/

Comment: The code shown never calls `pack()`.  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @davidbuzatto Unfortunately yes, as I really need to know the code I am building.

Comment: @ Andrew Thompson I'll keep SSCCE in mind for next time.  Re the pack(), when I use it it resizes the window which is not what I really need.  However I'll look it up as I am still in doubt on its use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

afaics, centralPanel has default layoutManager, which is FlowLayout. This always sizes its children to their prefSize, so the glue never comes into play.

Nesting containers comes at a price (which nesting wizards like @Andrew happily pay :-) Also, it's not entirely trivial to get right (f.i. replace the upper textField with a comboBox to see the mis-alignment). In the longer run, there's hardly a route around learning to master a more powerful manager, like f.i. MigLayout (my current personal favorite)

Comment: Yes centralPanel has default layoutManager but then I added two panels within, each using BoxLayout.  It is within this BoxLayout that I am adding the vertical Glue.  Does this make a difference in what you say?

Comment: the glue doesn't change the prefSize of the boxes, it only takes excess space which never happens if the _box_ is in a FlowLayout :-)